# how can i read data from other desktop application

Tags: c#, amibroker

I have created application in c# for auto trading purpose I want to  connect my application to amibroker software to  catch buy/sell signal generated by afl from amibroker to my application.. to execute order to my broker terminal.
I have tried using com communication but not success. how to achieve.. welcome to any  any sample code..
also I want to fetch ltp of  stock in any control like in gridview,textbox etc..
thanks

Comment: If the other app doesn't have an API, you can try a robotic process automation solution like Power Automate Desktop https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/desktop/

Comment: It would be nice if you added a minimum reproducible example so we can see what the actual problem is.

Comment: example is   something like a robotrading tool  a windows application generate  event to connect with amibroker (charting software which use afl program ) and take signal buy/sell for further execution. at real time . a communication with 3rd party software communication

Answer (score -1):

Try VBscript.
I send data from amibroker to excel using vbscript.

I use shellexecute to call the vbs file.  With parameters as well.

I have no idea if VBscript would be able to exchange data with C#.

I think it could be done.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).